# Adding new site to Ngnix

Tags: nginx

I am really new to Nginx, and am to add a new website to a remote Nginx server.

I notice that `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` has been modified to this:

```
server {

server_name api.example.com;

    root   /var/www/html/api/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

I want to add another url: `testapi.example.com` to the same server.  All the tuturiols point to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, but that folder is empty. This is a production machine, so I would not like bring any downtime.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another server block to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf for your second domain or a better way would be to create a new .conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ (with a meaningful name) and in that file define a new server block for the second domain.

So you'd keep your /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    server_name api.example.com;

    root   /var/www/html/api/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

And add /etc/nginx/conf.d/testapi.conf

```
server {
    server_name testapi.example.com;

    root   /var/www/html/testapi/root;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    ... rest of config for second domain...
}
```